# ¿Como puedo hacer un buscador con filtros con javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy utilizando react y material ui necesitó hacer un buscador en donde el usuario escriba el tipo de filtro que desea y dependiendo de ese filtro buscar dentro de un arreglo de objetos.

Por ejemplo, el usuario escribe:

"Type:name name:juan"

En este caso buscaría en él arreglo de objetos, todas las key "name" y despues buscaria él "name" con el nombre que se haya escrito, es decir "juan".

Otro caso seria que él usuario busque por él tipo person o company, para esto hay una key llamada "rol" en donde esta específicado si es person o company. Asi: rol: 'person'.
el usuario escribe:

"Type:person status:active"

En este caso buscaría por todas las key "rol" y buscaria todas las "person"y despues la key "status"

he intentado lo siguiente:

`  const handleSearch = (event) => {
const value = event.target.value.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();

```
console.log(value);

if (value.includes('type:name')) {
  const clients = rows.filter((row) =>
    row.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '').includes()
  ).map((row => row));

  setClients(clients);
}`
```

Pero no encuentro la manera de como leer dos valores en est caso el siguiente valor que seria el nombre.

Ayuda porfavor

Comment: Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar lo que has intentado, explicando la dificultad o error encontrado. De lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada por falta de un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he actualizado mi pregunta con el ejemplo de lo que he intentado